# angular input box with searchable dropdown

Tags: html, angular, typescript, input, dropdown

I am trying to add input box and below is my code. The input is not getting displayed

component.html

```
   <form [formGroup]="formGroup" (validSubmit)="onSubmit()">
     <div class="form-group mb-3">
       <label class="form-label">Age</label>
         <ng-select [items]="ages"
          [selectOnTab]="true"
           bindValue="value"
           labelForId="age"
           placeholder="Select age"
           formControlName="Age">
           </ng-select>
     </div>      
   </form>
```

component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup, Validators} from "@angular/forms";
 
@Component({
    selector: 'demo-form-validation',
    templateUrl: './basic-validation.html'
})
export class DemoFormBasicValidationComponent implements OnInit {
    formGroup: FormGroup;
 
    ages: any[] = [
        { value: '<18', label: 'Under 18' },
        { value: '18', label: '18' },
        { value: '>18', label: 'More than 18' },
    ];
 
    constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder) {}
 
    ngOnInit() {
        this.formGroup = this.formBuilder.group({
            Age: [null, Validators.required],
        });
    }
}
```

app.module.ts

```
import { NgBootstrapFormValidationModule } from 'ng-bootstrap-form-validation';
import { NgSelectModule } from '@ng-select/ng-select'
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

@NgModule({
    declarations: [
        AppComponent
    ],
    imports: [
        NgBootstrapFormValidationModule.forRoot(),
        NgSelectModule,
        FormsModule
    ],
    providers: [
    ],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

below is the image i am expecting[image]

here is the output i am getting. Only the label is getting displayed

[image]

Comment: With NgSelectModule you cannot see an input, but you can start to write when you click the select. Try

Comment: @Guiditox Apart from label nothing is there. not able to type anything

Comment: see this link and do step by step: https://www.npmjs.com/package/@ng-select/ng-select

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem a while ago.

This is what I tried and it should fix the problem with the display of the drop down list:

In your `styles.css` file add the following import:

```
@import "~@ng-select/ng-select/themes/default.theme.css";
```

On application refresh the drop down will render as expected.

In the link below is also a mention about theming for the `ng-select` component:

https://github.com/ng-select/ng-select#getting-started